# MinMax plot as ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I made a plot using the `plot()` command with a complex legend. Also, I have 3 other `ggplots()` . When trying to create a multiple plot using `grid.arrange()` from the **gridExtra** package with all 4 plots, I get this error. It's because I cant make a grid with 3 ggplots and 1 basic plot.

ERROR:

> Error in gList(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1,
>   height = 1,  :    only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

So I tried to "convert" my `plot()` to `qplot()` but I am getting this output:

[image]

And this is my desired output:

[image]

Here is my entire function, creating Min and Max points and plotting them into p2().

```
inflect <- function(x, threshold = 1)
{
  up   <- sapply(1:threshold, function(n) c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n)))
  down <-  sapply(-1:-threshold, function(n) c(rep(NA,abs(n)), x[-seq(length(x), length(x) - abs(n) + 1)]))
  a    <- cbind(x,up,down)
  list(minima = which(apply(a, 1, min) == a[,1]), maxima = which(apply(a, 1, max) == a[,1]))
}

# Pick a desired threshold # to plot up to
n <- 2
bottoms <- lapply(1:n, function(x) inflect(smooth$amount, threshold = x)$minima)
tops <- lapply(1:n, function(x) inflect(smooth$amount, threshold = x)$maxima)
# Color functions
cf.1 <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("pink","red"))
cf.2 <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("cyan","blue"))

p2 <- qplot(smooth$amount, type = 'l', main = "Minima & Maxima")

for(i in 1:n){
  points(bottoms[[i]], smooth$amount[bottoms[[i]]], pch = 16, col = cf.1(n)[i], cex = i/1.5)
}
for(i in 1:n){
  points(tops[[i]], smooth$amount[tops[[i]]], pch = 16, col = cf.2(n)[i], cex = i/1.5)
}
legend("topright", legend = c("Minima",1:n,"Maxima",1:n), 
       pch = rep(c(NA, rep(16,n)), 2), col = c(1, cf.1(n),1, cf.2(n)), 
       pt.cex =  c(rep(c(1, c(1:n) / 1.5), 2)), cex = .75, ncol = 2)
```

My data:

```
  date         amount
2012-07-01   1.970755
2012-08-01   3.976561
2012-09-01   5.180346
2012-10-01   5.671865
2012-11-01   5.370846
2012-12-01   3.884054
2013-01-01   3.214452
2013-02-01   3.483037
2013-03-01   3.777904
2013-04-01   3.990532
2013-05-01   4.051390
2013-06-01   3.748177
2013-07-01   3.160887
2013-08-01   2.894250
2013-09-01   3.034773
2013-10-01   3.027029
2013-11-01   2.980137
2013-12-01   2.870456
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good start. I didn't mess with the different sized points, but this is the general format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table2(" date         amount
2012-07-01   1.970755
2012-08-01   3.976561
2012-09-01   5.180346
2012-10-01   5.671865
2012-11-01   5.370846
2012-12-01   3.884054
2013-01-01   3.214452
2013-02-01   3.483037
2013-03-01   3.777904
2013-04-01   3.990532
2013-05-01   4.051390
2013-06-01   3.748177
2013-07-01   3.160887
2013-08-01   2.894250
2013-09-01   3.034773
2013-10-01   3.027029
2013-11-01   2.980137
2013-12-01   2.870456")

df %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date),
         max  = ifelse(lead(amount) < amount & lag(amount) < amount, amount, NA),
         min = ifelse(lead(amount) > amount & lag(amount) > amount, amount, NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date))+
  geom_path(aes(y = amount))+
  geom_point(aes(y = max, color = "Maxima"), size = 3, show.legend = T)+
  geom_point(aes(y = min, color = "Minima"), size = 3, show.legend = T)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))+
  labs(color = "")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-09-20 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately R crashes/freezes when I want to install the tidyverse package...can I reproduce your solution without using tidyverse?

Comment: Yes, sorry ‘tidyverse’ is just a habit and is a collection of packages. You can use the same code loading only dplyr, gglot2, and lubridate